# "Inheritance" of a CSS selector

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Is there a way for a CSS class to essentially say do these commands and also the commands of another class?

The use case is that I have a 2 column site using Bootstrap. At the moment, I'm not certain what the relative widths will be and it would be nice to be able to change that in one place in my SCSS file rather than go to every instance of left-column and right-column and add in the required bootstrap classes.

Comment: Why not just give the desired target more specificity? Your selector will override any Bootstrap selectors, and your rules will take effect. Then you won't have to add any new classes to any elements - just make use of the original Bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can call Boostrap grid/column settings using Sass mixins.

For example:

```
.your-left-column {
    @include make-col(8);
}

.your-right-column {
    @include make-col(4);
}
```

This should allow you to set your grid/column widths in one or very few places.

Details here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mixins

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simplest approach is best!

If your issue is that you've got a bunch of:

```
class="left-column col-md-4"
```

And perhaps you change your mind and desire

```
class="left-column col-md-6"
```

Then a "Find and replace across documents" may work best. Most, if not all, coding editors will have this feature. If you've been consistent with your class naming conventions this could work really well!

Comment: I'm hoping to use the bootstrap classes i.e. col-md-5, col-md-7, etc. They have a number of properties and if Bootstrap changes, stuff could break if I just copy over the classes.

Comment: Ah, right. I would assume that you would make these changes in the HTML or however you're generating it. Otherwise, perhaps you are looking to override the default breakpoints?

Comment: Are you setting rules with `.left-column .col-md-X` or something?

Comment: yes. I don’t know what x will end I being and want to be able to change it in one place rather than search and replace all instances of where I have left-column.